# Synching Leads from Marketo to SFDC as MQl is not working

Tags: marketo

I have done the synching of leads from Marketo to SFDC with member status as MQL. But the lead status' are not updated as MQL in SFDC end. They are still showed in as a 'Suspect' (previous status).

I have used Marketo campaign ('Add to SFDC Campaign' flow action) to run the leads from Marketo to SFDC.

Thanks

Comment: I would surmise that you are using the wrong sync action - 'Add to SFDC Campaign' merely associates a Lead to a Campaign in SFDC, it does not update the Lead (it will create a Lead if it doesn't exist - but that is not your use case). Leads are associated to Campaigns via the SFDC Object CampaignMember - a junction object. see https://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Add+to+SFDC+Campaign

Answer (score 0):

Is the value still not showing in SFDC after 15 hours? Marketo-SFDC sync is not instant but it should not take too long. Unless there is already a big batch of leads waiting to be sync with SFDC. For example, unrelated to your campaign, there might be a list upload which triggered a large number of leads to be sync with SFDC. Marketo processes the lead sync in batches of 200 each time and so it might take some time for your lead to get picked up.

But ‘Sync Lead to SFDC’, ‘Add to SFDC Campaign’ and ‘Change Owner’ Flow Actions do not wait for periodic sync and run when they are called immediately. So that does not add up. Reach out to Marketo support.

Useful links:
http://brightaspects.com/tips-marketo-sfdc-integration/

Hope that helps.

Rajesh